# Unable to capture the wild card(Garbage) word in speech recognition using SRGS namepsace C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, speech-recognition

I am a developing a C#.net application using speech recognition grammar specification (SRGS) namespace. I like to capture the wild card word. I have seen some examples where wild card word is captured using GrammarBuilder, But I am using SRGS namespace. I could not find any way to capture using this SRGS namespace.

I have written the below code to capture wildcard word. Below code should recognize phrases like " Execute report call statistics for E080755 event number:

```
SrgsOneOf reportsList = new SrgsOneOf();
reportsList.Add(new SrgsItem("Call Statistics"));

SrgsRule reportName = new SrgsRule("ReportName");
reportName.Add(reportsList);
reportName.Scope = SrgsRuleScope.Public;

SrgsRule executeReportRule = new SrgsRule("ExecuteReport");
SrgsItem executeReportWord = new SrgsItem("Execute report");
executeReportRule.Scope = SrgsRuleScope.Public;

SrgsItem forWord = new SrgsItem("for");
SrgsRule wildCardRule = new SrgsRule("WildCardRule");
wildCardRule.Scope = SrgsRuleScope.Public;


wildCardRule.Add(SrgsRuleRef.Garbage);
SrgsRuleRef wildCardRuleref = new SrgsRuleRef(wildCardRule, "WildCardWord");

SrgsItem eventNumberWord = new SrgsItem("event number");


executeReportRule.Add(executeReportWord);
executeReportRule.Add(new SrgsRuleRef(reportName, "ReportName"));
executeReportRule.Add(forWord);
executeReportRule.Add(wildCardRuleref);
executeReportRule.Add(eventNumberWord);

SrgsDocument document = new SrgsDocument();
document.Rules.Add(new SrgsRule[] { reportName, executeReportRule, wildCardRule });

document.Root = executeReportRule;

Grammar grammar = new Grammar(document, "ExecuteReport");

// Write the completed grammar to an XML-format SRGS grammar file.
System.Xml.XmlWriter writer =
System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create("c:\\Temp\\EventNumberGrammar.grxml");
document.WriteSrgs(writer);

writer.Close();
```

Tried to capture wild card word using "WildCardWord" semanti key . but i could get only "..." instead of original spoken word.

Thanks,
Vamshi Epuri

Comment: You need to use dictation instead of wildcard

Comment: namespace not namepsace, typ0 even if that almost deserves to be a word, sounds cool

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...
"SrgsRuleRef.Garbage" means you expect some unimportant text till the aproach of the next explicitly expected word.
You cannot access it because it is declared to be "garbage".